# Force acting on a coil in a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

so I have been taught that there is no force acting on the bit marked (?) even after if a coil rotates 90 degrees, can someone explain why even after the part marked (?) rotates 90 degrees there will be no force acting on it even if it's perpendicular to the magnetic field

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When at 90 degrees there are forces acting on the conductors marked **?** in the plane of the coil but those forces do not contribute a torque about the axle of the coil.

[image]

Comment: could further illustrate what is the forces that act on the (?) part of the coil

Comment: like what is their direction and so on

Comment: I have moved the coil round through $90^\circ$ and shown the force on one of the sides.

Comment: @Farcher How, please, did you modify this diagram? What application did you use? [My IT knowledge is negligible.]

Comment: I used Corel PaintShop Pro but there are many applications that can do the same thing and some of them are free!

Comment: @Farcher Amazing! Many thanks.

Comment: thank you so much , what a dumb question from me

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the right hand rule to the questioned segments, you should find that the forces are equal and opposite and produce no torque about the axis of rotation.

Comment: thank you so much , what a dumb question from me